# Regex for negative and positive numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, integer

I need a regex for an input field to allow negative and positive numbers and no alphabet/special characters. I have seen other people achieve this but they allow the minus sign at any point in the string whereas I only want to allow the minus sign at the beginning of the string.

Note: I want to allow the user to use the arrow, del, home keys etc.

Comment: `[-+]?\d+` accepts one or more digits that may or may not have a plus `+` or minus `-` in front of them.  I don't follow what you mean about arrow keys, that's not really something regex interacts with

Comment: `0.125`, `-.4`, `0xbabe`, `1e-23`, `Infinity`, `۸۹۸` etc - do you consider these to be "numbers"?

Answer (score 5):

This the regex to get positive and negative numbers :

```
^-?\d+$
```

If you want decimal numbers you can use this :

```
^-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

The parameter {1,2} at the end is for precision of your decimal number.

Comment: `[-]{0,1}` can be written shorter as `-?`

Comment: This isnt quite what i wanted. I actually need to stop user input in a text field if it is not a number, however, I want to allow the minus sign as a first character and nowhere else in the string

Comment: I think ill just use the HTML5 number input

Comment: Use number input is the best way for your problem. But if you really want use regex you can use one of two regex above.