# How to allow both negative and positive numbers in input with regex?

Tags: javascript

I was just learning form validation in React and decided to use regex. What I want to achieve is to allow both negative and positive numbers in a form. Here is my regex I am using `/^[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/i`. But this does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include negative decimal numbers in this regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814592/how-do-i-include-negative-decimal-numbers-in-this-regular-expression)

Comment: Why do you accept numbers with "+" in front?

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186188/regex-for-negative-and-positive-numbers

Comment: I've tried your regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/TTqyst/2) and it works. What's the problem?

Comment: @mthrsj, hi, I am just trying to add validation to input field and make sure error is shown ONLY when user types in anything except for positive or negative numbers. That is, only positive and negative numbers should be allowed. But, with my code, only positive is allowed:(

Comment: Paste in your question the code that manipulates your input. The problem doesn't seem to be with the regex

Comment: Has nothing to do with React

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below expression, you have to escape `+` and `-` with `\`

```
let reg = /\d+|\-\d+/gi;
let match = reg.exec("10"); // [ "10" ] valid 
let match2 = reg.exec("-10"); // [ "-10" ] valid
let match3 = reg.exec("abcd"); // null invalid

if(match === null){
    console.log('please enter positive or negative number');
}
```

Comment: sorry but even positive numbers are considered as not valid:(

Comment: match will happen only if you provide positive number or negative number. What do you want to find in regex, number which is positive or negative, right?

Comment: what I want is that when I type positive or negative number, there should not be any validation error. But if I type anything except for positive or negative numbers, there should be an error shown. Again only positive and negative numbers.

Comment: You can use above regex for same.  arrays match and match2 will be `null` if it contains some invalid thing except positive and negative number.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a polyfill for testing if a string is numeric by utilizing `isNaN` and `isFinite`, or you can use a regular expression.

**Caveat:** The latter will not work for numbers e.g. `42e1` (`420`) for example.

```js
/** Custom Polyfill */
if (String.prototype.isNumeric === undefined) {
  String.prototype.isNumeric = function() {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(this)) && isFinite(this);
  }
}

const IS_NUMERIC = /^[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
const isNumeric = (str) => IS_NUMERIC.test(str);

var numbers = [ "-0.1", "1.56", "+5.43", "42e1" ];
numbers.forEach((n, i) => {
  console.log(`[${i}] ${n} is ${isNumeric(n)} && ${n.isNumeric()}`);
});
```